# How can you unit test ASP.NET Web API routing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to write some unit tests to ensure that requests made to my Web API are routed to the expected API controller action with the expected arguments.

I've tried to create a test using the `HttpServer` class, but I get 500 responses from the server and no information to debug the problem.

Is there a way to create a unit tests for the routing of an ASP.NET Web API site?

Ideally, I'd like to create a request using `HttpClient` and have the server handle the request and pass it through the expected routing process.

Comment: OK, I am confused. You said *"I'm trying to write some unit tests to ensure that requests made to my **Web API** are routed to the expected API controller action with the expected arguments"* and *"Is there a way to create a unit tests for the routing of an **MVC site**"*. Which one? Also, please provide some code.

Comment: @tugberk does the distinction between MVC and WebAPI matter? The routing configuration is common to both platforms...

Comment: @MattDavey it absolutely does! Web API routing is not directly tied to `System.Web.Routing` and the action selectors of both frameworks behave completely differently. It's almost always a good idea to test Web API routing with integration testing (directly or indirectly as I stated in my answer).

Comment: I removed the mention of MVC for clarity - I am dealing with the Web API framework and it's so different from MVC, the distinction really matters. Additionally, what code would you have liked to see? My decrepit unit tests aren't worth showing.

Comment: The WebApiContrib project makes it pretty straightforward to test the mapping from URLs to Actions & Arguments: https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib.Testing/RouteTestingExtensions.cs  Example: https://gist.github.com/carolynvs/4471039

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have written a blog post about testing routes and doing pretty much what you are asking about:

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/testing-routes-in-asp-net-web-api/

Hope it helps.

Additional advantage is that I used reflection to provide action methods - so instead of using routes with strings, you do add them in a strongly typed manner. With this approach, if your action names ever change, the tests won't compile so you will easily be able to spot errors.

Comment: It would be useful if there was some code provided, supplying a link that is no longer active is hardly a useful accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry, I clicked the link on multiple computers and my phone and I was not getting a page returned.  I have confirmed that I can get there now.  Hopefully it answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: @FilipW, it appears to me from your article that you have to redefine the routes for your application in your unit tests.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't that entirely miss the point?  (since you're not testing the actual routes you're using in your application)

Comment: you can use any routes you want - you just need to set them up on the HttpConfiguration in the tests (i.e. call WebApiConfig.Register(config) from the tests, or any other central method you'd have to attach routes to a config object.

Comment: @FilipW Great article - could you maybe post the examples here also? ya know incase you won't be able to keep your own blog post ;)

Comment: It's adavisable to bring at least the bare minimum of an external article (a not SO article) just in case the external article dissapears. Could you update your answer with a little bit of info?

Comment: The link has gone inactive and the answer doesn't even give a summary of the information on the link.

Answer (score 9):

The best way to test your routes for your ASP.NET Web API application is the integration test your endpoints.

Here is simple Integration test sample for your ASP.NET Web API application. This doesn't mainly test your routes but it invisibly tests them. Also, I am using XUnit, Autofac and Moq here.

```
[Fact, NullCurrentPrincipal]
public async Task 
    Returns_200_And_Role_With_Key() {

    // Arrange
    Guid key1 = Guid.NewGuid(),
         key2 = Guid.NewGuid(),
         key3 = Guid.NewGuid(),
         key4 = Guid.NewGuid();

    var mockMemSrv = ServicesMockHelper
        .GetInitialMembershipService();

    mockMemSrv.Setup(ms => ms.GetRole(
            It.Is<Guid>(k =>
                k == key1 || k == key2 || 
                k == key3 || k == key4
            )
        )
    ).Returns<Guid>(key => new Role { 
        Key = key, Name = "FooBar"
    });

    var config = IntegrationTestHelper
        .GetInitialIntegrationTestConfig(GetInitialServices(mockMemSrv.Object));

    using (var httpServer = new HttpServer(config))
    using (var client = httpServer.ToHttpClient()) {

        var request = HttpRequestMessageHelper
            .ConstructRequest(
                httpMethod: HttpMethod.Get,
                uri: string.Format(
                    "https://localhost/{0}/{1}", 
                    "api/roles", 
                    key2.ToString()),
                mediaType: "application/json",
                username: Constants.ValidAdminUserName,
                password: Constants.ValidAdminPassword);

        // Act
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        var role = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RoleDto>();

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(key2, role.Key);
        Assert.Equal("FooBar", role.Name);
    }
}
```

There are a few external helpers I use for this test. The one of them is the `NullCurrentPrincipalAttribute`. As your test will run under your Windows Identity, the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` will be set with this identity. So, if you are using some sort of authorization in your application, it is best to get rid of this in the first place:

```
public class NullCurrentPrincipalAttribute : BeforeAfterTestAttribute {

    public override void Before(MethodInfo methodUnderTest) {

        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = null;
    }
}
```

Then, I create a mock `MembershipService`. This is application specific setup. So, this will be changed for your own implementation.

The `GetInitialServices` creates the Autofac container for me.

```
private static IContainer GetInitialServices(
    IMembershipService memSrv) {

    var builder = IntegrationTestHelper
        .GetEmptyContainerBuilder();

    builder.Register(c => memSrv)
        .As<IMembershipService>()
        .InstancePerApiRequest();

    return builder.Build();
}
```

The `GetInitialIntegrationTestConfig` method is just initializes my configuration.

```
internal static class IntegrationTestHelper {

    internal static HttpConfiguration GetInitialIntegrationTestConfig() {

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(config.Routes);
        WebAPIConfig.Configure(config);

        return config;
    }

    internal static HttpConfiguration GetInitialIntegrationTestConfig(IContainer container) {

        var config = GetInitialIntegrationTestConfig();
        AutofacWebAPI.Initialize(config, container);

        return config;
    }
}
```

The `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes` method basically registers my routes. I also have a little extension method to create an `HttpClient` over the `HttpServer`.

```
internal static class HttpServerExtensions {

    internal static HttpClient ToHttpClient(
        this HttpServer httpServer) {

        return new HttpClient(httpServer);
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a static class called `HttpRequestMessageHelper` which has bunch of static methods to construct a new `HttpRequestMessage` instance.

```
internal static class HttpRequestMessageHelper {

    internal static HttpRequestMessage ConstructRequest(
        HttpMethod httpMethod, string uri) {

        return new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, uri);
    }

    internal static HttpRequestMessage ConstructRequest(
        HttpMethod httpMethod, string uri, string mediaType) {

        return ConstructRequest(
            httpMethod, 
            uri, 
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(mediaType));
    }

    internal static HttpRequestMessage ConstructRequest(
        HttpMethod httpMethod, string uri,
        IEnumerable<string> mediaTypes) {

        return ConstructRequest(
            httpMethod,
            uri,
            mediaTypes.ToMediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValues());
    }

    internal static HttpRequestMessage ConstructRequest(
        HttpMethod httpMethod, string uri, string mediaType, 
        string username, string password) {

        return ConstructRequest(
            httpMethod, uri, new[] { mediaType }, username, password);
    }

    internal static HttpRequestMessage ConstructRequest(
        HttpMethod httpMethod, string uri, 
        IEnumerable<string> mediaTypes,
        string username, string password) {

        var request = ConstructRequest(httpMethod, uri, mediaTypes);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "Basic",
            EncodeToBase64(
                string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password)));

        return request;
    }

    // Private helpers
    private static HttpRequestMessage ConstructRequest(
        HttpMethod httpMethod, string uri,
        MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue mediaType) {

        return ConstructRequest(
            httpMethod, 
            uri, 
            new[] { mediaType });
    }

    private static HttpRequestMessage ConstructRequest(
        HttpMethod httpMethod, string uri,
        IEnumerable<MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue> mediaTypes) {

        var request = ConstructRequest(httpMethod, uri);
        request.Headers.Accept.AddTo(mediaTypes);

        return request;
    }

    private static string EncodeToBase64(string value) {

        byte[] toEncodeAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
    }
}
```

I am using Basic Authentication in my application. So, this class has some methods which construct an `HttpRequestMessege` with the Authentication header.

At the end, I do my *Act* and *Assert* to verify the things I need. This may be an overkill sample but I think this will give you a great idea.

Here is a great blog post on [Integration Testing with HttpServer](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/asp-net-web-api-integration-testing-with-in-memory-hosting/). Also, here is another great post on [Testing routes in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/testing-routes-in-asp-net-web-api/).

Comment: Informative answer, but why is this better than unit testing your routes?

Answer (score 2):

hi when you going to Test your Routes the main objective is test GetRouteData() with this test you ensure that the route system recognize correctly your request and the correct route is select.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("http://localhost:5240/foo/route", "GET", false, null, null)]
[InlineData("http://localhost:5240/api/Cars/", "GET", true, "Cars", null)]
[InlineData("http://localhost:5240/api/Cars/123", "GET", true, "Cars", "123")]
public void DefaultRoute_Returns_Correct_RouteData(
     string url, string method, bool shouldfound, string controller, string id)
{
    //Arrange
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    WebApiConfig.Register(config);

    var actionSelector = config.Services.GetActionSelector();
    var controllerSelector = config.Services.GetHttpControllerSelector();

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(method), url);
    config.EnsureInitialized();
    //Act
    var routeData = config.Routes.GetRouteData(request);
    //Assert
    // assert
    Assert.Equal(shouldfound, routeData != null);
    if (shouldfound)
    {
        Assert.Equal(controller, routeData.Values["controller"]);
        Assert.Equal(id == null ? (object)RouteParameter.Optional : (object)id, routeData.
        Values["id"]);
    }
}
```

this is important but is'not enough, even checking that the correct route is selected and the correct route data are extracted does not ensure that the
correct controller and action are selected
this is a handy method if you not rewrite the default **IHttpActionSelector** and **IHttpControllerSelector** services with your own.

```
 [Theory]
        [InlineData("http://localhost:12345/api/Cars/123", "GET", typeof(CarsController), "GetCars")]
        [InlineData("http://localhost:12345/api/Cars", "GET", typeof(CarsController), "GetCars")]
        public void Ensure_Correct_Controller_and_Action_Selected(string url,string method,
                                                    Type controllerType,string actionName) {
            //Arrange
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);

            var controllerSelector = config.Services.GetHttpControllerSelector();
            var actionSelector = config.Services.GetActionSelector();

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(method),url);

            config.EnsureInitialized();

            var routeData = config.Routes.GetRouteData(request);
            request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpRouteDataKey] = routeData;
            request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;
            //Act
            var ctrlDescriptor = controllerSelector.SelectController(request);
            var ctrlContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, request)
            {
                ControllerDescriptor = ctrlDescriptor
            };
            var actionDescriptor = actionSelector.SelectAction(ctrlContext);
            //Assert
            Assert.NotNull(ctrlDescriptor);
            Assert.Equal(controllerType, ctrlDescriptor.ControllerType);
            Assert.Equal(actionName, actionDescriptor.ActionName);
        }
    }
```